# remove underline with :hover:before

Tags: css, html

'm using a font to create icons for my navigations in the following example :
http://www.blackcountrydesigns.co.uk/examples/green/

The problem I'm having is when you hover over a link you get an underline on both the link and the icon.

I want to know how can I remove the underline on the icon but keep it on the link.

Here's my code :

```
HTML
<ul class="hidden-phone">
         <li><a class="entypo-home" href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="entypo-briefcase" href="#">Services</a></li>
         <li><a class="entypo-picture" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a class="entypo-address" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

CSS
#nav ul li a {color:#ccc; margin-left: 25px;}
#nav [class*='entypo-'].active:before {color:#666;}
#nav [class*='entypo-']:before {font-size: 46px; position: relative; top: 5px;left: -3px; color:#999;}
[class*='entypo-']:hover:before {text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Many thanks

Comment: I what to remove the underline for all icon not just the active one.  I'll remove the .active class to avoid confusions

Comment: And what CSS are you using? (Not just the CSS that doesn't work, but the whole of the CSS for the list.)

Comment: +1 An interesting question! I made a simplyfied fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGHpg/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I've found, as yet, to remove the (normally) inherited styles from the generated content is to give it `position: absolute`, using the simplified demo (from the comments):

```
a:link
{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:before
{
    content: '#';
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NGHpg/1/).

The down-side of this approach, of course, is the requirement of an explicit `width` being assigned to the generated-content (and to the `margin` of the parent `a` element).

Comment: That's look to be doing what I want.  However I'm confused about the width: 1em because it still works without that.

Comment: The width is only necessary because the generated content is being explicitly positioned outside of its parent element; it's to ensure that it's not covered by, or covering, another element is all.

Comment: Yes great thinking Dave.  All the smart people are called Dave :P  I'm the only exception to that rule :D

Comment: Thanks, @Linus! And, David, modesty forbids me from commenting..! ;)

Comment: I can sleep now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to wrap the text of the link in an element, e.g. span, remove underline from the 'a' and apply it to the span on hover.

```
<li><a class="entypo-home active" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>

[class*='entypo-'] a { text-decoration: none; }
[class*='entypo-'] a:hover span { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that doesn't work. I would suggest giving the class your `<li/>` and set the `:before` for those.

In case you don't want to use the `position: absolute` approach, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGHpg/2/) of my suggestion.

Comment: Yes that's your fiddle is telling me :(